# Reporting Services Web Proxy path is not a wsdl

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, service-reference

I am trying to follow this example:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa179614%28SQL.80%29.aspx#

It says to add the following path as a Web Reference:

```
http://myserver/reportserver/reportservice.asmx
```

I have tried that (using my server name for myserver) and it always returns an error.

When I try it as a Web Reference it says "The HTML document does not contain Web service discovery information."

How can I add this service?  I am clearly missing something that is not in the docs.  Has anyone ever been able to add a web reference (or Service Reference) for SSRS?  If so, how was it done?

Note: I am using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate and SQL Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using SQL server 2008 R2, the correct web service should be:

> http://myserver/reportserver/reportservice2010.asmx

Use web browser to load this to verify.

Comment: This did not work.  I tried to browse to it I get the same view as with out the "2010" (a list of folders and data sources).  When I use it as a web reference I get the same error that I got above.

Comment: Seems to me your report web service is not installed/setup correctly. Are you sure the SSRS is installed correctly in your server? If yes, you should be able to load the link above with web browser and see the wsdl definition.  Or maybe is the security settings to prevent you from running the web service.

Comment: Turns out I thought I had SQL Server 2008 R2.  I really have SQL Server 2008 SP1.  So I had to use ReqportService2005.asmx.  Thanks for the answer.  I am marking it as correct.

Answer (score 2):

You need to request the WSDL definition from the service by adding the ?wsdl

> http:///reportserver/reportservice2010.asmx?wsdl

There is more information on this at this link [Creating the Web Service Proxy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155134.aspx)